# Bare 'raise' inside a finally block

Tags: python, exception

I want to execute a function, and if the result is None or an exception was raised, I would like to do something. In addition, if an exception was raised I would like to re raise it after finishing.

The following code works, however it doesn't look like the right solution, and I didn't find any documentation on using a bare `raise` inside a `finally` block. What is the correct solution here?

```
exception_caught = False
try:
    result = func()
except:
    result = None
    exception_caught = True
finally:
    if result is None:
        handle_none_or_exception()
    if exception_caught:
        raise
```

Update: I know it can be done by calling `handle_none_or_exception()` more than once however I don't want to do it as that's actually a code fragment I don't want to change or duplicate.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need the `finally` clause at all - you can check if `result` is None inside `else`:

```
try:
    result = func()
except:
    handle_none_or_exception()
    raise
else:
    if result is None:
        handle_none_or_exception()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `finally` section is a cleanup section executed no matter what happened in the `try-except` section.

In your case you have several disctint cases (error, no error and None value, no error and not None value). That's why a `finally` block is not suitable for the task and I guess that was ment by your comment "*it doesn't look like the right solution*".

There is a hint in the docs ("try statement") which makes bare raise impossible:

> The exception information is not available to the program during
>   execution of the finally clause.